# Formatting my table Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table that has the following columns

```
select a.ssrmeet_crn
      ,a.ssrmeet_begin_time
      ,a.ssrmeet_end_time
      ,a.ssrmeet_start_date
      ,a.ssrmeet_end_date
      ,a.ssrmeet_sun_day
      ,a.ssrmeet_mon_day
      ,a.ssrmeet_tue_day
      ,a.ssrmeet_wed_day
      ,a.ssrmeet_thu_day
      ,a.ssrmeet_fri_day
      ,a.ssrmeet_sat_day
from   ssrmeet a
where  a.ssrmeet_term_code = 201730
and    a.ssrmeet_crn = 32789
```

A row for one class would look like this

```
SSRMEET_CRN SSRMEET_BEGIN_TIME  SSRMEET_END_TIME    SSRMEET_START_DATE      SSRMEET_END_DATE        SSRMEET_SUN_DAY SSRMEET_MON_DAY SSRMEET_TUE_DAY SSRMEET_WED_DAY SSRMEET_THU_DAY SSRMEET_FRI_DAY SSRMEET_SAT_DAY
32789       1000                1050                1/8/2018 12:00:00 AM    5/4/2018 12:00:00 AM                    M                               W                               F
```

I need it to list out every class meet like this

```
CRN     START_DATE              END_DATE
32789   1/15/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/15/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/22/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/22/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/29/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/29/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/05/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/05/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/12/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/12/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/19/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/19/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/26/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/26/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/05/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/05/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/12/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/12/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/19/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/19/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/26/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/26/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/02/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/02/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/09/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/09/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/16/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/16/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/23/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/23/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/30/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/30/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/10/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/10/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/17/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/17/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/24/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/24/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/31/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/31/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/07/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/07/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/14/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/14/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/21/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/21/2018 10:50:00 AM
2789    2/28/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/28/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/07/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/07/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/14/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/14/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/21/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/21/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/28/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/28/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/04/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/04/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/11/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/11/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/18/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/18/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/25/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/25/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   5/02/2018 10:00:00 AM   5/02/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/12/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/12/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/19/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/19/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   1/26/2018 10:00:00 AM   1/26/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/02/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/02/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/09/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/09/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/16/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/16/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   2/23/2018 10:00:00 AM   2/23/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/02/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/02/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/09/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/09/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/16/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/16/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/23/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/23/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   3/30/2018 10:00:00 AM   3/30/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/06/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/06/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/13/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/13/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/20/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/20/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   4/27/2018 10:00:00 AM   4/27/2018 10:50:00 AM
32789   5/04/2018 10:00:00 AM   5/04/2018 10:50:00 AM
```

The day columns just have indicators if the class meets on that day. (Sunday 'U', 
Monday 'M', 
Tuesday 'T', 
Wednesday 'W', 
Thursday 'R', 
Friday 'F', 
Saturday 'S')

and the begin times and end times are in 24hour format.

I've tried a couple different paths to try and solve including using connect by this but I'm stumped.

This is as far as I've gotten with it. I can generate the first dates with it but I don't know where to go from here..

```
with
data_prep as(
select 'U' dotw_code, 'Sunday' week_day from dual
union all
select 'M', 'Monday' from dual
union all
select 'T', 'Tuesday' from dual
union all
select 'W', 'Wednesday' from dual
union all
select 'R', 'Thursday' from dual
union all
select 'F', 'Friday' from dual
union all
select 'S', 'Saturday' from dual
)



select a.ssrmeet_crn crn
      ,case b.dotw_code
       when 'U'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_begin_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'SUN')
       when 'M'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_begin_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MON')
       when 'T'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_begin_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'TUE')
       when 'W'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_begin_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'WED')
       when 'R'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_begin_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'THU')
       when 'F'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_begin_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'FRI')
       when 'S'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_begin_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'SAT')
       end start_date
      ,case b.dotw_code
       when 'U'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_end_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'SUN')
       when 'M'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_end_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MON')
       when 'T'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_end_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'TUE')
       when 'W'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_end_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'WED')
       when 'R'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_end_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'THU')
       when 'F'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_end_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'FRI')
       when 'S'
       then
       next_day(to_date(to_char(ssrmeet_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' ' || ssrmeet_end_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'SAT')
       end end_date
from   ssrmeet a
       left join data_prep b
          on a.ssrmeet_sun_day = b.dotw_code
          or a.ssrmeet_mon_day = b.dotw_code
          or a.ssrmeet_tue_day = b.dotw_code
          or a.ssrmeet_wed_day = b.dotw_code
          or a.ssrmeet_thu_day = b.dotw_code
          or a.ssrmeet_fri_day = b.dotw_code
          or a.ssrmeet_sat_day = b.dotw_code
where  ssrmeet_term_code = 201730
and    ssrmeet_crn = 32789
```

If anyone could help out or even give me pointers on how to properly format my question on the forums I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It would help if you added some sample data in your ssrmeet table and the expected output you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (that you'd like to have a list of the dates the meetings are supposed to happen between the start and end dates), then I think the following query should work for you:

```
WITH ssrmeet AS (SELECT 32789 ssrmeet_crn, 201730 ssrmeet_term_code, to_date('01/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ssrmeet_start_date, to_date('01/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ssrmeet_end_date, NULL sun_day, NULL mon_day, 'T' tue_day, 'W' wed_day, NULL thu_day, 'F' fri_day, 'S' sat_day FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 32790 ssrmeet_crn, 201730 ssrmeet_term_code, to_date('05/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ssrmeet_start_date, to_date('27/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ssrmeet_end_date, NULL sun_day, NULL mon_day, 'T' tue_day, 'W' wed_day, NULL thu_day, 'F' fri_day, 'S' sat_day FROM dual)
SELECT ssrmeet_crn,
       ssrmeet_start_date,
       ssrmeet_end_date,
       dt,
       to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') dt_day,
       CASE WHEN (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Mon' AND mon_day = 'M')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Tue' AND tue_day = 'T')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Wed' AND wed_day = 'W')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Thu' AND thu_day = 'R')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Fri' AND fri_day = 'F')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Sat' AND sat_day = 'S')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Sun' AND sun_day = 'U')
                 THEN  dt
       END meet_dt
FROM   (SELECT ssrmeet_crn,
               ssrmeet_start_date,
               ssrmeet_end_date,
               ssrmeet_start_date - 1 + LEVEL dt,
               sun_day,
               mon_day,
               tue_day,
               wed_day,
               thu_day,
               fri_day,
               sat_day
        FROM   ssrmeet
        CONNECT BY ssrmeet_crn = PRIOR ssrmeet_crn
                   AND ssrmeet_term_code = PRIOR ssrmeet_term_code
                   AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
                   AND LEVEL <= ssrmeet_end_date - ssrmeet_start_date + 1)
WHERE  CASE WHEN (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Mon' AND mon_day = 'M')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Tue' AND tue_day = 'T')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Wed' AND wed_day = 'W')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Thu' AND thu_day = 'R')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Fri' AND fri_day = 'F')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Sat' AND sat_day = 'S')
                 OR (to_char(dt, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Sun' AND sun_day = 'U')
                 THEN  dt
       END IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ssrmeet_crn,
         ssrmeet_start_date,
         dt;

SSRMEET_CRN SSRMEET_START_DATE SSRMEET_END_DATE DT          DT_DAY MEET_DT
----------- ------------------ ---------------- ----------- ------ -----------
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       01/03/2017  Wed    01/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       03/03/2017  Fri    03/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       04/03/2017  Sat    04/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       07/03/2017  Tue    07/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       08/03/2017  Wed    08/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       10/03/2017  Fri    10/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       11/03/2017  Sat    11/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       14/03/2017  Tue    14/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       15/03/2017  Wed    15/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       17/03/2017  Fri    17/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       18/03/2017  Sat    18/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       21/03/2017  Tue    21/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       22/03/2017  Wed    22/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       24/03/2017  Fri    24/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       25/03/2017  Sat    25/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       28/03/2017  Tue    28/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       29/03/2017  Wed    29/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       31/03/2017  Fri    31/03/2017
      32789 01/03/2017         01/04/2017       01/04/2017  Sat    01/04/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       07/03/2017  Tue    07/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       08/03/2017  Wed    08/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       10/03/2017  Fri    10/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       11/03/2017  Sat    11/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       14/03/2017  Tue    14/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       15/03/2017  Wed    15/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       17/03/2017  Fri    17/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       18/03/2017  Sat    18/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       21/03/2017  Tue    21/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       22/03/2017  Wed    22/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       24/03/2017  Fri    24/03/2017
      32790 05/03/2017         27/03/2017       25/03/2017  Sat    25/03/2017
```

This works by first of all doing a hierarchical query, producing a row for each date between the start and end dates (adding 1 to include the start_date in the results). This will produce the hierarchical query for each row if there is more than one row. If you are only expecting to do this for a single row at a time, you only need the last line in the connect by clause (the first three are necessary to make the hierarchy for each row, rather than across the set of rows. I assume that ssrmeet_term_code, ssrmeet_crn is unique).

Once you have this list, you can then check the day flags to see if the date is one of the flagged days, and if it isn't, don't output it. (N.B. since you didn't provide any sample data or expected output, I've had to guess at the table contents and the expected output.)

If you have any chance of being able to change the design, I would go with a simple Y/N (or Y/null) in the day flag columns, rather than each column having its own individual flag (i.e. mon_flag = Y, tue_flag = Y, etc, rather than mon_flag = 'M', tue_flag = 'T', etc)

Comment: This works great! I added the sample data and expected output but you beat me to the punch. I have to do some brushing up on my hierarchical queries. Don't think I've every used sys_guid() before

Comment: Also if you don't mind me asking how do you format the result of you query in text? I use Toad Data Point as an IDE and it doesn't seem to have a result to text option. That would help for sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: I don’t use Toad Data Point, so I can’t say. However, most IDE’s have a way to export the data, either to the clipboard or to a file. You’d have to google how to do that with TDP.